# Objective-C NSString Autorelease Issue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I just spent the last two hours slamming my forehead against my code, trying to figure out what was wrong with it.  I eventually narrowed it down to one pair of lines.

```
NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

if ([components count] > 1){                        
    retainedProperty1 = [header objectAtIndex:0];

    retainedProperty2 = [header objectAtIndex:1];
}
```

Whenever I attempted to access either of these fields after a delay in execution (I'm using [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/), and it would pull in the rest of the data I needed for this object in a second read from the socket), they would both have become zombies. I was just wondering why the heck this was happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're lying to yourself. You're saying `retainedProperty1 = ...` but you're actually assigning to the ivar, not the property. Unless you're using ARC (and you're not or you wouldn't have this problem), this doesn't do any memory management whatsoever. It won't even free the previous value of this ivar. You should be saying

```
self.retainedProperty1 = ...
self.retainedProperty2 = ...
```

Comment: Ah, thanks muchly. That sorts the issue (I had resorted to the classic stick-poking technique, and had already sort of stumbled onto this, when I had switched over to [self setRetainedProperty1:object]